# AppArmor equivalent to Firejail --net=none

Tags: networking, apparmor, sandbox

`firejail --net=none` creates a sandbox looking like a computer without any network interfaces.

Is it possible to achieve the same result with AppArmor? It looks like, AppArmor's `deny network` just denies everything, but doesn't hide the network interfaces from the application.

Comment: The short answer is no. Now if you explained *why*, in order to solve what specific problem, you are asking this question, maybe you could get a more useful answer. See http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: This is a valid answer to my question. I will accept it.

Comment: I'll try to say a bit more, but not much more than "no" then in the answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason firejail makes the network interfaces "disappear" is that it runs the application in a new [network namespace](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/network_namespaces.7):

> DESCRIPTION
>
> Network namespaces provide isolation of the system resources
> associated with networking: network devices, IPv4 and IPv6 protocol
> stacks, IP routing tables, firewall rules, the `/proc/net` directory
> (which is a symbolic link to `/proc/PID/net`), the `/sys/class/net`
> directory, various files under `/proc/sys/net`, port numbers (sockets),
> and so on.
> [...]

The new network namespace has initially no interface (except its own local instance of the `lo` interface), that's why the application doesn't see any interface (except `lo`) nor can do any useful network-related action.

[AppArmor](https://manpages.debian.org/apparmor/apparmor.7) creates additional restrictions to a program when it accesses resources, that will prevent operations normally permitted by the user running the program to succeed. So you could perhaps imagine AppArmor could be configured to prevent an application to successfully access or interact with the the various resources mentioned in the previous quote, but it won't make them disappear.  The application will get a difference in the result: it won't receive an answer telling the result is empty or that there's no such object, but will instead receive an error when asking for it. The answer to the question is thus: no.

Note: `firejail --net=none` does more than just isolating the network namespace. It does much more work, including preventing to even query about those interfaces (thus also getting errors when trying), and isolating most other namespaces too (user, pid, mount, ...).

There are plenty of other tools available for isolation. Even if in some cases it's possible they overlap in functionalities, they are often all used together. For example Firejail can be used along Apparmor, [SELinux](http://www.selinuxproject.org/page/Main_Page) (an alternate method to AppArmor) or [cgroups](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/cgroups.7). Or for example there's also the use of [seccomp(2)](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages-dev/seccomp.2) which can in some cases lie to an application telling it the requested action was successfully done while it wasn't. That's an example, I don't think it's usable either for preventing to see network interfaces.